# Search and replace multiple patterns in a string in python script

Tags: python, regex, bash

I am attempting to create a python script that does the following:

1. Prompts the user to input a string
2. Strip all characters from `'hxxps://'` to `'u='`
3. Replace `'hxxp-3A__' with 'http://'`
4. Replace all `'_'` with `'/'`
5. Delete all characters from `'&d='` to the end of the string(including &d)

Example of the string the user would be prompted to enter to be decoded:

```
<b>hxxps://emailfiltervendor.com/v2/url?u=</b>hxxp-3A__developer.apple.com_contact<b>_&d=AAMC-Q&c=zQ6tLaF7dShu6emFdFLQLQ&r=Omg3VPeUzekjh8aAoyWWiIblQyDVxual9qHMwJiqOpQ&m=MtC66x1fgSnrN9foA74EcYf6Ekmp0vmUDRLTGVtTQcU&s=xHGspXPb32hmzbF1rkJ2jWRvS011WqvwsU1LSM4zQdU&e=</b>
```

What the output should look like:

```
hxxp://developer.apple.com/contact/
```

I've tried various combinations of the following script but can't seem to search/replace more than 1 string(http-3a__ for http://). My last script attempt included the following:

```
!/usr/bin/python
import re

str = "http-3A__camcogm.com_americanexpress.com&d=AAICaQ&c=zQ6tLaF7dShu6emFdFLQLQ&r=AfgFWq3_k20u3QSxhfE-TPsRXxWcDPc0YcZAhO55eV0&m=S_APJ9UeCnO7zAnBcvb2jKu_XvZJkrzyy0N$

print re.sub("http-3A__", "http://", str), ("&d*.*"," ", str);   
print re.sub("&d*.*"," ", str);
```

Please help!!!

Comment: You're missing a closing `"` at the end of your `str` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first example with the Apple URL, this code works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

string = "hxxp-3A__developer.apple.com_contact_&d=AAMC-Q&c=zQ6tLaF7dShu6emFdFLQLQ&r=Omg3VPeUzekjh8aAoyWWiIblQyDVxual9qHMwJiqOpQ&m=MtC66x1fgSnrN9foA74EcYf6Ekmp0vmUDRLTGVtTQcU&s=xHGspXPb32hmzbF1rkJ2jWRvS011WqvwsU1LSM4zQdU&e="

string = string.replace('hxxps://',"u=")
string = string.replace('hxxp-3A__','http://')
string = string.replace('_','/')
string = re.sub(r'&d=[\s\S]*','',string)

print string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
>>> val=re.sub(r'hxxps.*u=hxxp-3A__([^&]+).*', r'hxxp://\1', str)
>>> re.sub(r'_', '/', val)
'hxxp://developer.apple.com/contact/'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can  use replace this is the syntax:

```
string.replace(str ,old, new[, max])
```

so for you it would by

```
import string
str = "your text"
string.replace('str'hxxp-3A__','http://')
string.replace('str','_' , '/' )
sep = "&d="
str.split(sep, 1)[0]
str = str(0)
```